# Array operations: -X[array_name] result?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; //initialization 
  cout << -3[arr]; //line A
  return 0;
}
```

How is the output of line A -4? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run here http://cpp.sh/4y6kp. Output is -4 every time.

Comment: @tobi303 No UB here, the `operator[]` has higher precedence than unary minus.

Comment: @BaummitAugen arghs, missed that

Comment: @tobi303 So did I at first, admittedly.

Comment: `-3[arr]` is actually `-(3[arr])`

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Every time it amazes me how easy it is to forget C++ doesn't have negative integer literals.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, but fortunately that's a dusty corner of the standard that's not relevant to real-world code.

Comment: `a[n]` == `*(a+n)` == `*(n+a)` == `n[a]`.  1st conversion is standard definition of array indexing.  2nd conversion is basic maths. 3rd conversion is reverse of 1st.